# RAID 5 setup across SATA II/III

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, raid, sata

I have an ASUS P8Z77-V LK mobo with 4 SATA 3Gb/s and 2 SATA 6Gb/s.  I'm considering purchasing 3 WD7500AZEX HDD's and putting them in a RAID 5 configuration.

My question is, if I put the two striped drives on the SATA 6GB/s, will the entire array clock down (I'm sure there's a better term for it) to match the speed of the third drive that's handling the parity for the raid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. An array is only as fast as it's slowest drive. It writes one bit to each drive in series, so any speed gains you get on fast drives is lost on the slow ones.

Comment: Ok, makes sense.  I might ultimately just throw my current 500gb on a 6Gb/s and use it for junk storage then outside of the array.  But thank you very much!